# Parsing XML feed in PHP

Tags: php, xml, curl

```
<?php

$url='http://bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml';

$c = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$rawXML = curl_exec($c);

curl_close($c);

$fixedupXML = htmlspecialchars($rawXML);

foreach($fixedupXML->eta-> as $eta) {
  echo $eta->destination;
}

?>
```

As a way to get introduced to PHP, I've decided to parse BART's XML feed and display it on my webpage. I managed (also via this site) to be able to fetch the data and preserve the XML tags. However, when I try to output the XML data, using what I found to be the simplest method, nothing happens.

```
foreach($fixedupXML->eta as $eta){
  echo $eta->destination;
}
```

Am I not getting the nested elements right in the foreach loop?

Here is the BART XML feed http://www.bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml
Thanks!

Comment: What does this mean: `$fixedupXML->eta->` ? it seems there is an additional `->` or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at [simplexml](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php), which is a fantastic and really simple way to work with XML.
Here's a great example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://bart.gov/dev/eta/bart_eta.xml');
```

Then you can run a `print_r` on `$xml` to see it's contents:

```
print_r($xml);
```

And you should be able to work with it from there :)

If you still need to use curl to get the feed data for some reason, you can feed the XML into simplexml like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($rawXML);
```